# Wordpress using a different php.ini to what php --ini reports

Tags: php, macos, php-7, php-ini

I spent ages trying to work out why my Wordpress installation wasn't recognising changing in my php.ini. It turned out that my Wordpress install was using a different `php.ini` file.

When I run:

```
CRMPiccos-MacBook:~ crmpicco$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-pdo_pgsql.ini
```

However, when I look at a `phpinfo()` page inside my Wordpress app it is looking at a `php.ini` which lives in `/usr/local/php5/lib/`.

[image]

Why is this and where is this configured?

Comment: problem probably come from your apache configuration. You say you are on OSX, do you use software like Mamp or have you installed Apache and php manualy ?

Comment: I installed MAMP a while ago, but I don't use it now. It's still installed, but i'm reluctant to remove it incase it breaks my local setup.

Comment: You probably need to modify your httpd.conf (his location depend of your system) to change php version to use. The line to edit probably starting by `LoadModule php[...]` and restart apache

Comment: @Fabien Hmmm, thanks for your comment. However, edit which module? There are numerous `LoadModule` entries in my Apache config. I don't understand why `php --ini` would report one single location, yet Wordpress would be using another? Is this issue localised to my WP install or all virtual host configurations on my machine?

Comment: you need to change the line related to php module in apache configuration. the difference betweek php --ini and phpinfo is because the php configuration in your terminal is defined in the $PATH variable (of the terminal) while the php configuration used by your web server (Apache) is configured in httpd.conf. Can you post a copy of your Apache httpd.conf ?